# How do generators in space transmit/ deposit energy back to Earth?

Tags: heat-transfer, energy, energy-storage, generator

I've read about the idea of putting solar panels in space, or the already used electrodynamic tethers which gain energy as they move through Earth's magnetic field.

The question I have is:

How do you get the generated energy back to Earth?

Comment: Better on Space Exploration...

Comment: beam of microwaves

Comment: yes, let's make it a well-aimed beam of microwaves.

Comment: Beams of microwaves or laser light. See Wikipedia [Space-based Solar Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-based_solar_power)

Comment: @nielsnielsen, ... and aim it at the solar-roadways project :D

Comment: @wossname I'm sure nothing could possibly go wrong with that

Comment: @niels It does not have to be all that powerful of a beam. All it has to do is be collectible from one direction then we can collect it from a big area. Think of it like a solar powerplant thats more efficient due to no day and night or relative movement of source.

Comment: @joojaa, a microwave antenna of such size would be an expensive proposition. I do not know if the economics would work out for that or for the collector array which would need to be erected in space. have you googled this idea? it has been written about on and off over the years.

Comment: @nielsnielsen yes and it has been calculated to work. Some countries are actually trying to implement it.

Comment: VTC as overly broad. There is an enormous amount of discussion of the topic on the web. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-based_solar_power.  You seem to be asking for a rehash of all of it.

Answer (score -4):

Generators in space are mainly used as nuclear power source in space where solar power is not a viable power source. The different space generators in use today are radioisotope thermoelectric generator and radioisotope piezo electric generator. This generator  converts energy stored in a radioactive material directly into motion to generate electricity by the repeated deformation of material.

As far as the transmission of energy is considered, it can be achieved by perpetual motion which is most possible in space the on earth. In space the weightless space helps to achieve perpetual motion which oppose the law of conservation of energy. Hence the energy can be tried to transmit back to earth from generators in space through perpetual motion.perpetual motion is motion of bodies that continue indefinitely.the laws of thermodynamiccs apply even at very grand scales.example,motions and rotations of celestial bodies such as planets may appear perpetual,but are subjected to many processes that dissipate kinetic energy,such as solar wind,interstellar medium resistance,gravitational radiation and thermal radiation,so they will not keep moving forever.there is a scientific consensus that perpetual motion in an isolated system voilates either first law of thermodynamics,or second law of thermodynamics or both.Depending on this criteria perpetual motion machines are clasified as
perpetual motion machine of first kind which produces work without the input of energy,it thus voilates the first law of thermodynamics.
pertual motion machine of second kind is a machine which spontaneously converts thermal energy into mechanical energy.when the thermal energy is equivalent to workdone it does not voilate first law of thermodynamics but voilates second law.
perpetual motion machine of third kind is defined as one that eleminates friction and other dessipative forces completely.it is impossible to  make such a machine as the dessipative forces cannot be completely eleminated.but it can be reduced to the limit in space.
hence using one of the criteria with the generators in space we can try to transmit energy back to earth.

Comment: Why is solar power not a viable power source in space? Could you elaborate more on the actual question of _how_ the generated power would be transmitted back to earth?

Comment: Mr Irfan, much as I admire your devastating left-arm quick bowling, your understanding of physics and engineering leaves much to be desired.